# form fields clear?

Tags: forms, field

i want to clear the fields of my form after the user has inserted the data in the database .I have provided a button for that but how to do that please tell me

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: You need to identify the platform and development tools you're using

Comment: also do you want to clear the fields automatically or just when the user clicks a button?

Comment: Is it Win Forms, HTML forms or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type='reset' id='btnResetFields' value='Clear Fields' />
```

sets the form elements back to their initial state when the form was first loaded. [Web Application]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web application you can use reset button:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset values" />
```